# Android: How to programmatically set dialog size?

Tags: android, user-interface

I want do set size (in px) of dialog based on screen resolution, so I have to set dialog size programmatically during runtime.

Dialog layout is defined in xml with all standard views, so it would be nice to have better way to set dialog size than override-in top view's onMeasure(...).

(Android 1.5 SDK)

Comment: It's a bad idea to try to set the exact size of anything in your interface.  Why are you using px instead of dip?

Comment: ...but, I'm trying to set exact size only in runtime, not designtime.

Comment: But why?  Why not let Android set the proper size at runtime based on the dip/sp values you provide at designtime?

Comment: Eventually, I gave the dialog size in dips.
In activity, I'm taking care of screen/view/canvas dimensions in pixels, so it felt really ok to use that info to set dialog size manualy, but... :(

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would suggest reading Google's Dev Guide on supporting multiple screen sizes.

http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html

Using pixels for view sizes is a bad idea.